# Is there any way to pass multiple label inputs to predict one label using svm

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

Sample data:

name       description        location
Rose       kind of flower     Kashmir,ooty
Onion      Kind of vegetable  Gujarat

I need to pass the one record (string1,string2).This two string  which is 
dataset contains like

```
name    description
```

But i tried with passing one label and predicting another label using svm in python

```
#Python CODE
data=pandas.csv(data.csv)
data_1=data[0:800]
data_2=data[800:1000]
svm.fit(data_1['name'], data_1['description'])
svm.predict(data_2['name'])
print("enter the name")
i=str(input())
predicted=svm.predict(i)
print("predicted description is")
print(predicted)  #here the description will be predicted
```

But in above code i am passing only  title as input and predicting the description.

I extended the dataset by adding another column  as like location

So there will be three column in dataset like

```
name,description,location
```

So i need to pass now name and description as input and i need to predict the location as result

I don't know how to pass two labels (name,description) in predict() method to predict the location as result or any other solution available if applicable means please post the solution.

**EDIT:**

I changed the code as per comments:

```
#Python CODE  
data=pandas.csv(data.csv)  
data_1=data[0:100]  
data_2=data[50:100]  
svm.fit(data_1[['name','description']], data_1['location'])   
svm.predict(data_2['location'])  
print("enter the name")  
i=str(input())  
print("enter the description")  
j=str(input())      
predicted=svm.predict(i)  
print("predicted location is")  
print(predicted)    #here the location will be predicted
```

After running this code getting below error:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples[2,100] in svm_fit(data_1[['name','description']],data_1['location'])

Comment: Try: `svm.fit(data_1[['name','description']], data_1['location'])`

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: It is generating ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples[2,100] after adding the svm.fit(data_1[['name','description']], data_1['location']) instead of  svm.fit(data_1['name'], data_1['description']).Is there any other solution

Comment: Post your code in the question above. It should get sorted.

Comment: can you add the sample records from data variable?

Comment: Did it work? You should post feedback here.

Comment: No,it is generating same error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the mistake is in the following line

```
svm.predict(data_2['location'])
```

You need to give input data of `data_2`, like this one!

```
svm.predict(data_2[['name','description']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is incorrect:

```
print("enter the name")  
i=str(input())  
print("enter the description")  
i=str(input())      
predicted=svm.predict(i)
```

You should use:

```
print("enter the name")  
i=str(input())  
print("enter the description")  
j=str(input())  # using i here will lose name string.
predicted=svm.predict([i,j])  # send both name and description now;
```

But error seems to be coming from following statement:

```
svm.fit(data_1[['name','description']], data_1['location'])
```

Exact error can be found only if you post sample of data also.

Comment: I posted sample data above.Can u please tell me  how can I able to predict the location field.Is there any other solution from your side.

Comment: Is it as a dataframe or a numpy array? Put a sample in your question above.